# Fastify test unit keeps getting timed out (Node Tap)

Tags: node.js, graphql, integration-testing, tap, fastify

I am testing a NodeJS app on Fastify , using Node Tap. I'm new to both platforms.
The test case unit is supposed to connect to graphql and run a sample query. I can see that the query is executed and the test assertions being passed successfully :

```
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `title`, `type`, `description`, `published`,` FROM `articles` AS `Article` WHERE `Article`.`section_id` IS NOT NULL AND `Article`.`date_published` <= NOW() AND ORDER BY `Article`.`TITLE` ASC,LIMIT 5;
```

However, the test case keeps taking 30 seconds and eventually getting timed out. I

```
FAIL  test/fastify-tests.js
 ✖ timeout!

  test: TAP
  signal: SIGTERM
  handles:
    - type: Socket
      events:
        - end
        - data
        - error
        - clientError
        - close
        - drain
  expired: TAP
```

I also noticed it adds an extra assertion to the number of tests. For example , in the case where I have only one assertion , it states it is testing two :

```
Asserts:  1 failed, 1 passed, of 2
```

My test case :

```
const tap = require('tap');
const fastify = require('../fastifyapp');

tap.test('POST  to `/graphql` route', t => {
t.plan(1); //plan for 1 assertion
const app = fastify.FastifyApp();
app.inject({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost/graphql',
    payload: {
        "operationName:": null,
        "query": '{\n' +
            'article(limit: 5) {\n' +
            'id\n' +
            '}\n' +
            '}\n',
    "variables": {
        "visibility": "PUBLIC",
        "articletype": "SPORTS",
        "OFFSET": 0,
        "articleSortBy": "ID",
        "articleSort": "ASC",
        }
    }
}, (err, response) => {
    t.error(err);  // assertion 1
});
});
```

Would love it if someone could help me understand why :

- it times out every time
- it adds an extra assertion to the list of tests being taken in

Comment: Is the same request replying to you if you run the server in dev mode? If so, could you share the CURL?

Answer (score 0):

Add `t.end()` after your `t.error()` assertion

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your connection to the database.

---

#### *1. By Make use of fastify hooks:*

I have an example with mongoose and you can search postgresql, mysql, or whatever db you're connecting to:

```js
fastify
      .decorate('mongoose', db)
      .addHook('onClose', (fastify, done) => {
        fastify.mongoose.connection.close();
      });
```

#### *2. By separate the database connection:*

you can provide the database instance as an option. and define .close() callback function to call every time you make tests.